# Grails 2.3 & GGTS 3.4 stop button not working

Tags: grails, grails-2.3

How to stop grails processes in GGTS 3.4 with grails 2.3. the stop button of GGTS is not stopping the server running and the java.exe processes are still showing in task manager.

Comment: I remember a bug opened for this. The workaround is to run the grails command `stop-app`

Comment: even after the stop-app command, the processes are not stopped. The stop button is disabled

Comment: I have the same problem, I have to exit GGTS, kill the java process, then restart, a process which takes several minutes each time.

Answer (score 3):

Comment the `grails.project.fork = [ .. ]` part of your BuildConfig.groovy file.

This part enables running run-app, test-app and war in different threads(so you don't have to stop one to start the other), and it seems ggts isn't successfully destroying the thread right now.

For reference, here is the related issue in the ggts bug tracker https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3522

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to disable the "Keep external Grails running" option in Eclipse Preferences -> Groovy -> Grails -> Grails Launcher?

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the "Keep external Grails running" does not work for me.  What I do is to hit the "Grails Command History" icon and type "stopApp" (or pick stopApp if previously typed).  Once this commands finishes executing, then you can stop the Grails application using the stop button.

Comment: I am on Windows and stopApp works for me. If I run my app on multiple ports etc., like mine - I had to write a small custom script to end my processes i.e. java.exe etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using Groovy Grails Tool Suite GGTS 3.4.0 on windows 64x. For my simple projects, the stop button works.  For a bigger complex project, it does not.  I use the "stop-app" (opposite of "run-app").  See: 2.8 Running an Application [in the getting started guide](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/gettingStarted.html).  I think that in older versions of Grails ( < 2.x something) you had to create your own "stop-app" script.  I think the newer 2.3.x has it built in.

Comment: it seems ggts doesn't properly support grails's recent fork ability

Answer (score 0):

I am using **GGTS 3.5.1, Grails 2.3.8, Java1.7 over Windows configuration** the command is works for me **"stop-app"** and **"run-app"**